# send multiple data from Selectchain dropdown box with jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

How to send multiple data in select chain dropdown box,

PROCESS 1 GET VARIABLE kd_jenis and post into ambilkota.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var htmlobjek;
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("#kd_jenis").change(function(){
 var kd_jenis = $("#kd_jenis").val();
```

POST kd_jenis variable

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "ambilkota.php",
    data: "kd_jenis="+kd_jenis,
    cache: true,
    success: function(msg){

        $("#kd_fungsi").html(msg);
    }
});
});
```

PROCESS #2 i want kd_jenis from process 1 and kd_fungsi post into next page ambilbiaya.php

```
  $("#kd_fungsi").change(function(){
var kd_fungsi = $("#kd_fungsi").val();
```

POST kd_jenis variable from 1st step and post kd_fungsi from 2nd step, so it will send 2 data

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ambilbiaya.php",

    data: 'kd_jenis='+kd_jenis+'kd_fungsi='+kd_fungsi,
    cache: true,
    success: function(msg){

        $("#kd_sebutan").html(msg);
    }
});
});
});
```

But the second process not work.. im still cant send data kd_jenis from the first step to the step 3. its only will send kd_fungsi...

help me please...

Answer (score 0):

if both are in the same page then you can send the value directly,

try this

PROCESS #2

```
...
data: 'kd_jenis='+ $("#kd_jenis").val() +'kd_fungsi='+kd_fungsi,
...
```